# Are there any java code generator from byte code

Tags: java, generator

A program written in `java` should be compiled to byte code to run it in a computer. If the program is a closed source, I think `bytecode` that is human can understand. Or some day some one will be able to program a java code generator right? Isn't that an issue?

Comment: Are you trying to ask if there is a way to understand what byte code is doing? If so, you can actually examine the code, and figure that out rather simply, and there are already decompilers that exist (look up JD-GUI, for one example) that attempt to reconstruct source code from byte code.  And yes, it's an issue, which is why there are user agreements where you promise not to reverse engineer things.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean bytecode? Yes, your java program can be decompiled. If jvm can run it, it can be decompiled. You can obfuscate your program so decompilers will produce a hard-to-read java code